# How to replace specific words of each line with an alteration in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have an sql file like this:

```
Create new-table1 ... As select ..from table1;
Create new-table2 ... As select ..from table2;
Create new-table3 ... As select ..from table3;
```

And so on..

What I need ro do is append a **WHERE** clause at the end of each line,so that the queries will be like:

```
Create new-table1 ... As select ..from table1 where 1000<=(select count(1) from table1);
Create new-table2 ... As select ..from table2 where 1000<=(select count(1) from table2);
Create new-table3 ... As select ..from table3 where 1000<=(select count(1) from table3);
```

And so on...

Basically new table will be empty for all tables below 1000 rows.

Is there a way I can edit(find&replace) my file using notepad++ so that i can add this where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    from (\w+);$
Replace: from $1 where 1000 <= (select count(1) from $1);
```

### Demo